Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of variable
I have installed @fullcalendar/core & @fullcalendar/daygrid on a Ts based app. when I import is like
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core' import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
Ts shows: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'Calendar'.ts(2440)
How to resolve this
I was expecting normal execution since this is copied from the npm website code example

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I guess, there is Calendar variable/function in your file (where you're trying to import these things).
To avoid the error you need either to rename your variable/function in your file, or to rename import variable using as like this:
import { Calendar as FullCalendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'

Also, check, if your file not concatenated to another file where Calendar variable could exist
